# Converting python nested list with unequal elements in second layer to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Say that I have a nested list with unequal number of elements in the second layer like `a=[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8,9]]`. I also have corresponding list containing date variables like `b=[['Mon','Tues','Wed'],['Mon','Wed'],['Mon','Tues','Wed','Thur']]`. I would like to convert `a` and `b` to `pandas dataframes` since it is able to take in unequal rows, and then I would like to combine `a` and `b` into one `dataframe` and perform `merge` on the three dates columns to find the common dates and the corresponding values. However I am not sure how to convert the nested lists to dataframes. I tried converting them to `np.array` but it is unable to hold unequal rows.

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: 'dataframes since it is able to take in unequal rows' Really, since when.

Comment: @A1122 Is your problem is to construct dataframe from a  nested dict? or something else, if only df from nested dict then it's pretty simple.

Comment: Up to two level nesting you can use pd.DataFrame.from_dict(), for three level nesting you need to write few lines..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I could come up with is to zip up each record into a dictionary, create a single row dataframe for that row then concat (or outerjoin) this to the previous rows. Here's the code:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8,9]]
b = [['Mon','Tues','Wed'],['Mon','Wed'],['Mon','Tues','Wed','Thur']]
df = pd.DataFrame()

for row in zip(a,b):
    d = dict(zip(row[1], row[0]))
    dfrow = pd.DataFrame(d, index=[0]) #Dataframe for 1 row
    df = pd.concat([df, dfrow])
```

Gives this:

```
   Mon  Thur  Tues  Wed
0    1   NaN   2.0    3
0    4   NaN   NaN    5
0    6   9.0   7.0    8
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this `[dict(zip(keysA,keysB)) for keysA,keysB in zip(a,b)]` ... but it has nothing to do with pandas or numpy ...

```
>>> a=[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8,9]]
>>> b=[['Mon','Tues','Wed'],['Mon','Wed'],['Mon','Tues','Wed','Thur']]
>>> print [dict(zip(keysA,keysB)) for keysA,keysB in zip(a,b)]
[{1: 'Mon', 2: 'Tues', 3: 'Wed'}, {4: 'Mon', 5: 'Wed'}, {8: 'Wed', 9: 'Thur', 6: 'Mon', 7: 'Tues'}]
```

or maybe you want to switch day name to the key instead of the number ... its not really clear from your question ...

(something like `df = DataFrame([dict(zip(keysB,keysA)) for keysA,keysB in zip(a,b)])`)